# Rotate pandas DataFrame 90 degrees

Tags: python, pandas

Basically I want to rotate a pandas DataFrame by 90 degrees (clockwise), such that if it were

```
df:
    A B C D
  0 5 3 6 7
  1 6 3 5 2
```

it would turn into

```
df:
   6 5 A
   3 3 B
   5 6 C
   2 7 D
```

Is there some way to do this with pivots, or some other way? Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

transpose it

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame([[5,3,6,7],[6,3,5,2]],index=[0,1],columns=list('ABCD'))

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  5  3  6  7
1  6  3  5  2

In [3]: df.T
Out[3]: 
   0  1
A  5  6
B  3  3
C  6  5
D  7  2
```

I guess you REALLY want this

```
In [7]: df.T.reset_index().reindex(columns=[1,0,'index'])
Out[7]: 
   1  0 index
0  6  5     A
1  3  3     B
2  5  6     C
3  2  7     D
```

Comment: Exactly not what the OP asked for.

Comment: I updated to EXACTLY what the op stated, even though its not that useful

Comment: @Jeff it's silly to say that it's not useful It depends on the application. You could be storing image pixel information in a Pandas DataFrame, for example, and want it actually rotated with special handling of the label values. It is application-specific as to whether it's useful, and it's not usually relevant on SO to try to go outside the scope of the question and decide for the OP whether or not the OP's questions was "right."

Comment: Also, in your answer, you may want to remove the hard-coded column indexing, and do something like this: `temp_df = df.T.reset_index(); temp_df[temp_df.columns[::-1]]` for this particular kind of rotation.

Comment: I don't know about that; the example in the question doesn't have ANY indicies, so its not clear; that said, your suggestion in general is good!